# (-215:Assertion failed) number < max_number in function 'cv::icvExtractPattern' error?

Tags: python, opencv, pyinstaller

I'm trying to run this python script as an exe file - using pyinstaller, and it raise me this error:

> [ERROR:0] global C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap.cpp (415) cv::VideoWriter::open VIDEOIO(CV_IMAGES): raised OpenCV exception:
>   OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_images.cpp:267: error: (-215:Assertion failed) number < max_number in function 'cv::icvExtractPattern'

When I'm running it as a python script, it works well.
the python script:

```
SCREEN_SIZE = (1920, 1080)
FPS = 20.0
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"XVID")
out = cv2.VideoWriter("output.avi", fourcc, FPS, SCREEN_SIZE)
```

I'm using pyinstaller in the command line:

```
pyinstaller --onefile python_script.py
```

what should I change to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Main solution:** It could be a `DLL` error.

I suppose your problem is connected to [this issue](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2950). There is a workaround suggested in [this comment](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2950#issuecomment-455891842). It suggests to run pyinstaller as

`pyinstaller -F --add-data opencv_ffmpeg410_64.dll;. python_script.py`

Make sure to adapt to your OpenCV version. Make sure this dll exists anywhere.

**Alternative:**
I believe the error

> python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_images.cpp:267: error: (-215:Assertion failed) number < max_number in function 'cv::icvExtractPattern'

is caused by this line here `fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"XVID")` where the value that is set is `>` the max value.

You can try to set the fourcc to `-1`. Then, it will give you a choice of video codecs to use for writing. I have seen that uncompressed video choice works fine for most of the platforms.

Answer (score 0):

This error also occurs when there is a problem with the destination directory where the output files is to be saved, e.g., if the destination directory does not exists.

Answer (score 0):

This is absolutely crazy, but similar problem was fixed to me by renaming output file. If output filename includes too many digits then this goddamn number validation in cap_images will fail even if I use cv2.VideoWriter

https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4.x/modules/videoio/src/cap_images.cpp

```cpp
while (pos < len && isdigit(filename[pos]))
        {
            char ch = filename[pos];
            number = (number * 10) + (uint64_t)((int)ch - (int)'0');
            CV_Assert(number < max_number);
            number_str_size++;
            CV_Assert(number_str_size <= 64);  // don't allow huge zero prefixes
            pos++;
        }
```